# iPhone JSON Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I'll try and make this quick:

I've an external class that parses the JSON from a `webservice` (the JSON itself is fine, I've done it locally now I'm making it web accessible) and then these values will be used for comparisons. However I can't access the variables in every case. My intent is to parse them once and be able to access them whenever

The parser is being loaded from the the app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{ 
ld =[[ loader alloc] init];
[ld parse];
}
```

The contents of the `connectingDidFinishLoading`:

```
jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:re encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//NSLog(@"LOADER %@", jsonString);

SBJsonParser *parser = [SBJsonParser new];

se = (NSMutableDictionary *)[parser objectWithString:jsonString];

searchR = [se objectForKey:@"menu"]; 

s = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[searchR objectForKey:@"tip1"] ] retain];

NSLog(@"TROLL2 %@", [s objectAtIndex:0  ]);
```

This comes back correct

However in the first page loaded at the end of the viewDidLoad:

```
    lt = [[loader alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"CALLED %@", [lt.s objectAtIndex:0] );
```

This comes back null, and before anyone asks, `s` is a property of the loader class.
Just wondering if I need a callback to ensure the class is properly loaded or am I just having a stupid day and calling it wrong from the first page

```
 Here's the `timestaps`:
 2011-07-28 13:59:07.183 [44330:40b] TROLL2 top aaaft
 2011-07-28 13:59:07.371 [44330:40b] CALLED (null)
```

Thanks for your time reading this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't you have to access the app delegate rather than initialize a new one?

`MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

NSLog(@"CALLED %@", [delegate.lt.s objectAtIndex:0] );

Comment: I tried using singletons before and it caused mega errors, ill try it again

Comment: The parser nor the values are contained in the delegate, the delegate contains the call to the loader class where the parsing is begin
Its the loader I want to access from different classes

Also how can it be "[delegate.LT.s objectAtIndex:0]" if im not longing making a new instance of the loader class?

Comment: My mistake there... I missed something.  If 'ld' is a property, you should be able to access the 's' property from there.

Comment: Also, if you were to initialize it on the first page, wouldn't you have to call the 'parse' method as you did in 'applicationDidFinishLaunching'?

Comment: I think the problem is the parse can't get back fast enough, im calling the parse in the delegate, a print in the parse class to confirm the output comes after the null print from the first page loaded. Delegate Parse call (to parse class) : 1 . Landing page NSLog :2  . Parse class : 3